# Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OS disappeared after Installing Ruby 2.4.0 by rvm

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm using mac, and Ruby 2.0.0 had been built in within Mac OS.

I used rvm to install new version of Ruby, because I had heart that rvm could keep different versions of Ruby in computers and could well manage them.

I used the command to install Ruby 2.4.0:

```
$ rvm install 2.4.0 --disable-binary
```

Then check the Ruby versions kept by rvm :

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

There was only one version listed. Only Ruby 2.4.0.

The Ruby 2.0.0 was not displayed. **Why？**

---

**The Ruby 2.4.0 can be found by `which ruby`: `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby`**

**But I can find that the /library/Ruby contain the Ruby 2.0.0, it exists in my computer.**

**Why Ruby 2.0.0 is not displayed by rvm?**

Answer (score 2):

`rvm list` shows you the list of rubies you've installed through rvm, but doesn't say anything about your system ruby. If you want to use your system ruby, try `rvm use system`, and then `which ruby` to confirm that you're using /usr/bin/ruby.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! It confused me for a long time.  Then `rvm use default` could change back to the rvm Rubies.

Answer (score 1):

`rvm list` does not display the system Ruby version in the list. That command only displays the Ruby versions that were installed through RVM. If you want to switch back to the system version of Ruby, run the command `rvm use system`. After running that command, `ruby -v` should display that it is version 2.0.0.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! It confused me for a long time. Then `rvm use default` could change back to the rvm Rubies.